# Subtle version of "Curtains match the carpet"

Tags: idioms, offensive-language, synonyms

The idiom "the curtains match the carpet" -- also heard the other way around and, in American English, swapping in "drapes" and "rug", respectively; I think I've also heard it with "collar" and "cuffs", too -- is used to question whether someone who has dyed their hair has just paid attention to the hair on their head, or has done a more, let's say, "thorough job".

It is quite an obvious analogy. Especially when carpet/rug serves as relatively common slang for a woman's pubic hair and curtains/drapes are quite a good simile for long hair... My point being that you'd have to have lived quite a sheltered existence to neither have ever heard this, nor be able to figure out its meaning!

Is there a drop in replacement which is more subtle, without being a euphemism (e.g., unlike my "thorough job", above)?

Comment: In any social context I can get my head around, the idea of ***subtly*** referencing the colour of a woman's pubic hair seems inherently contradictory / oxymoronic (unless the reference is so subtle no-one picks it up, but I'd still say it was crass to take the risk).

Comment: Just sayin'--I think these expressions describe only whether a woman dyes the hair on her head, or doesn't. She most likely doesn't dye anywhere else, so it's not about whether she's been "more thorough". And as I'm writing this, I'm watching an American Idol contestant with platinum blond hair and brown eyebrows.

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying.  The expressions you refer to are not that common in most circles, and, while I vaguely recall hearing one once or twice and sort of working out it's meaning, I suspect they leave a lot of people confused.  Kind of a long way round Robin Hood's barn to say "Do you think she's a natural blonde?"

Comment: I would venture that it's not possible to subtly determine the colour of anyone's pubic hair by conversation.

Comment: Voting to Close as Primarily opinion-based as the question asks for a replacement which is "***more subtle***" - clearly a subjective comparison.

Comment: You could always ask if she uses a merkin for intimate moments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Natural** blonde, brunette, redhead etc?
That *usually* implies match upper and lower thatch.